# Opencart 3 пользовательский контроллер каталога

Tags: php, mvc, opencart, twig, шаблонизаторы

Кто в курсе, как реализовать контроллер в Opencart 3.0.2.0, который будет отвечать по адресу SEO URL на frontend.
в общем имеем контроллер (catalog/controller/extension/module/my_obmen.php):

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMyObmen extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/my_obmen');
        $data['status'] = $this->config->get('module_my_obmen_status');
        return $this->load->view('extension/module/my_obmen', $data);
    }
}
```

при обращении по ссылке https://opencart.local/extension/module/my_obmen возникает ошибка 404, а вот если обратиться по адресу https://opencart.local/index.php?route=extension/module/my_obmen то ответ 200, только страница пустая, хотя в шаблоне (catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/extension/module/my_obmen.twig) следующее содержимое:

```
<div>
    <h1>Obmen: </h1>
    <p>Status: {{ status }}</p>
</div>
```

Контроллер по "недружелюбной ссылке" отрабатывает вроде, если его чуть изменить:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMyObmen extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/my_obmen');
        $data['status'] = $this->config->get('module_my_obmen_status');
        echo $data['status'];
    }
}
```

То по ссылке https://opencart.local/index.php?route=extension/module/my_obmen
возвращает запрошенный статус, который равен 1, а по ссылке https://opencart.local/extension/module/my_obmen всё равно возникает ошибка 404

SEO на стороне CMS включено, штатные страницы работают по seo ссылкам. Пользовательский шаблон включён.
Вопрос заключается в следующем, как заставить работать контроллер по SEO ссылкам и чтобы он подтягивал шаблон?

По подтягиванию шаблона разобрался, вот так:

```
<?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleMyObmen extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/my_obmen');
        $data['status'] = $this->config->get('module_my_obmen_status');
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/my_obmen', $data));
    }
}
```

я так понимаю, чтобы переопределить адрес url нужно подключить модель seo и что то сделать, вот только что???

Comment: Кеш Opencart'а сбрасывали?

Comment: @Alexander Semikashev кэш на время написания модуля отключён. Но для верности удалял.